# Identical particles system with center of mass and relative coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, identical-particles

In order to properly express my doubts, I am afraid that I will need an introduction a bit longer than usual, so my apologies in advance for that. It is a doubt in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, and more precisely, it is on rewriting the operators of quantum mechanics from the particles operators to operators of center of mass and relative coordinates.

Let's assume we have a 2 particles quantum system, and let's firstly assume that the 2 particles are distinguishable from each other. In this case, it is possible to rewrite the dynamics and the state of the system either in terms of the position coordinates $x_1 and x_2$ or we can introduce the center of mass $X_{cm} = (m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2) / M$ and relative coordinates $r = x_1 - x_2$ . In this second case, the system is equivalent to a 2 particles systems, one with mass $M$ and one with mass equal to the reduced mass $\mu = m_1 m_2 / M$. All good so far.

Let's now assume that the two particles are identical and let's try to again move to the center of mass and relative coordinates. I have the following doubts:

1. In this case, we cannot have $X_{cm} = (m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2) / M$ and $r = x_1 - x_2$, because if hypothetically we measure both (they are independent coordinates after all) then we would be able to track also at the same time $x_1$ and $x_2$, making the particles distinguishables. Since $X_{cm}$ is symmetrized over the particles  1 and 2, it is a good operator for identical particles systems. But the relative coordinate $r$ is not symmetrized, and it has to be changed to something different. Am I missing something? What should be the relative coordinate position and momentum for 2 identical particles?
2. As possible relative coordinate operator for 2 identical particles I thought about $|x_1 - x_2|$. However, it is easy to see (for example, just rewrite it in second quantization formalism - you can use the expression in second quantization of an interaction potential as help) that it is a two-body operator. If it is a two-body operator, I cannot interprete the center of mass and relative coordinates as an equivalent 2 particles systems (as done initially for distinguishable particles). How to sort it out?
3. Finally, let's assume that it is possible to actually find a way to properly define the relative coordinates for identical particles systems, and that we are actually able to describe 2 identical particles in terms of center of mass with mass $M$ and relative coordinate with mass $\mu$. However, this would means that 2 identical particles systems are equivalent to a system of 2 distinguishable particles (since they have different masses!). I don't think this is possible.

Problems above make me think that, if we have identical particles, the definition fo center of mass and relative coordinates is different from the usual one. Am I right? What is the correct definition then?

Answer (score 0):

Your argument, if I understand it, is like this: when using a set of coordinates (arguments of psi function) that is the combination of the radius vector of center of mass $\mathbf R_{CM}$ and difference of the particle radius vectors $\delta \mathbf r$, if values of $\mathbf R_{CM},\delta \mathbf r$ were known, they would reveal the position of the particle 1 and the position of the particle 2, and thus this set of variables is not compliant with the assumption that particles are indistinguishable.

This argument makes no sense to me. The same argument could be made for set of coordinates $\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2$ - it is not compliant with the idea of indistinguishable particles. Yet we use description based on $\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2$ to describe states where particles are indistinguishable just fine.

This is because the indistinguishability is an additional constraint on $\psi$; it does not require us to change the set of coordinates used or to change the Hamiltonian or the Schroedinger equation. Both sets of coordinates (and other similar sets built from them) are fine to write down the Schroedinger equation. (Care should be taken when writing down commutation relations between the new coordinates and momenta, as they do not need to be always as simple as for the Cartesian coordinates.) The variables the $\psi$ is function of need not be distinguishable measurable physical quantities.

You seem to require that $\psi$ be written as a function of variables where each represents a measurable physical quantity that is distinct from the others. I don't think this is possible for multi-particle systems, at least not if those variables are to be combinations of particle radius vectors. It certainly is not the case when the system has identical particles and $\psi$ is taken to be function of $\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2,...$.

When it comes to measurements, the possibility that values of $\mathbf R_{CM},\delta \mathbf r$ are measured poses as little problem as the possibility that values $\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2$ are measured. In practice, when we measure position of some of the identical particles, when we get a value, we can't say which particle it belongs to, because (by assumption) there are no labels on the particles and they are all equivalent. I have no idea how we would go about measuring $\delta \mathbf r$. The best that we could do is measuring size of the system, which reveals $|\mathbf r_1 - \mathbf r_2|$ but not which particle is which.

Comment: Hi @JanLasinsky, my logic is the following, please let me know if there is any mistake. Let's assume we have 2 identical particles, and we are able to measure how the center of mass $< x_1 + x_2 > / 2$ and relative coordinates $< x_1 - x_2>$ evolve in time (< ; > here means average over the state). In this way, you can get the values of $<x_1>$ and $<x_2>$ evolve in time. So there is one observable, the position, that you can use to distinguish particle 1 from particle 2. That should not be possible.

Comment: Why do you assume we are able to measure $\langle x_1 - x_2\rangle$, when the particles are indistinguishable? Any measuring procedure will have trouble determining whether the measured thing corresponds to $x_1-x_2$ or to $x_2-x_1$. The only value we could consistently assign is zero. Then $\langle x_1 \rangle = \langle x_2 \rangle$ as it should be for indistinguishable particles.

Comment: I think we agree that, differently from the case of 2 distibguishable particles, in the case of 2 identical particles the relative coordinate $x_1 - x_2$ is not a good operator. Which means that, in the case of identical partilcles, the relative coordinates must be expressed by another operator. In my point 2 above I guessed (but it may be wrong) that it could be $|x_1 - x_2|$. However, this is a 2-body operator. As a consequence, the analogy "the system with two particles in x_1 and x_2 is equivalent to the system of two particles, 1 in $X_{cm}$ and the 2 in relative coordinate", doesn't work

Comment: Moreover, in point 3 (please let me know if I have to describe better my doubts) I say that, even if there is a good operator to express 2 identical particles in relative coordinates such that the system is equivalent to one particle in $X_{cm}$ and one in relative coordinate, then we would have a 2 identical particles system equvalent to a 2 distinguishable particles system (because total mass $M$ is different from reduced mass $\mu$). How is that possible?

Comment: It does not matter, as far as I can see, that $x_1-x_2$ is not a good operator. $x_1$ is not a good operator either, yet psi function is function of $x_1$ and the theory works. So it should work with $x_1-x_2$ too - it's just coordinate transformation.

Comment: Re point 3, it does not matter that the Hamiltonian in the new set of coordinates has two different masses. In the Hamiltonian, terms are already distinguishable in the original coordinates $x_1,x_2$. Indistinguishability is a property of the solution, not of the equations.

Comment: I agree that the state has to be symmetric or antisymmetric if identical particles, but this property must be preserved by time evolution and any operation you can make on the system. That is why you have to write also the operators symmetrically (and that is why second quantization is so useful). You can rewrite the state as center of mass and relative, but the relative, if identical particles, may not be convenient for the study of the system: for example, the state cannot factorize in energy eigenstate of cm $\otimes$ energy eigenstate of relative, see e.g. free Hamiltonian case